# Python 3.3's yield from

Tags: python, functional-programming, yield

Python 3 brings the [`yield from`](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380) semantics. As far as I understand it's supposed to yield to the outermost generator in which case I'd expect this code to be linear in `N`.

```
from collections import Iterable

def flatten(L):
  for e in L:
    if isinstance(e, Iterable):
      yield from flatten(e)
    else:
      yield e 

N = 100
L = [-1]
for i in range(N):
  L = [i, [L], i]
for i in range(100):
  f = list(flatten(L))
print(len(f))
```

If I set `N=200` however the computation time is about four times longer suggesting flatten is quadratic in the length of `L`. I can't understand why it would be since the code visits each element only once and the `yield from` keyword should be sending values directly from the inner generator to where the terms are collected into the list.

Is this a bug, simply not intended, or am I using it wrong? Is there a nice way to do O(N) flattening in Python?

Comment: Where are you timing from, remember exhausting a generator using `list` is expensive and time consuming.

Comment: How do you measure? Simply `time python thisfile.py`? Could you add a `timeit` benchmark? @JakobBowyer It is, but it's linear time. `list(x + 1 for x in range(100))` takes 13µs/loop for me, while the same with `range(200)` takes 22µs (rather than ballpark 40µs).

Comment: Also, in a recursive algorithm, there is a real cost of pushing and popping the stack.

Comment: You never gave us comparisons; using `timeit` I compared `yield from flatten(e)` vs. `for sube in flatten(e): yield sube`, and found the timedifference to be minimal (100 iterations takes 0.2840079980014707 vs 0.28362161200129776 seconds).

Comment: Last but not least: unflattening is not linear in N; it depends on the number of nestings as well, as `flatten` will be called to deal with each nesting encountered. So, the nesting factor M is to be taken into account as well. In the worst case, all N elements are contained in a new nesting level, resulting in O(NM) complexity.

Comment: Unflattening can be O(N+M) where N is the number of elements and M the number of Iterators. In the example above we make `l` such that M = O(N). It was timed with the Unix command `time`.

Answer (score 14):

`yield from`, just like `for item in x: yield x`, *is* linear.  However, function calls are slow, and because of the nesting in your `l`, when you double N, you're not merely doubling the number of terms, you're doubling the number of calls needed.  Anything which scales with the number of calls, like function overhead itself esp. due to the recursion, any `yield from` overhead, `for` loop initialization overhead, whatever, would therefore cause a problem.  If this is right, then we'd expect that a list with the same number of elements and no nesting would be linear, mid-nesting would be in-between, and lots of nesting would be super-slow.  And that's what we see:

```
import timeit

s = """

from collections import Iterable

def flatten(l):
   for e in l:
       if isinstance(e, Iterable):
           yield from flatten(e)
       else:
           yield e 

def build_lots(N):
    l = [-1]
    for i in range(N):
        l = [i, [l], i]
    return l

def build_some(N):
    l = [-1]
    for i in range(N):
        l = [i]+l+[i] if i % 2 else [i,[l],i]
    return l

def build_none(N):
    return range(2*N+1)

"""

def get_time(size, which_build, n=100):
    setup = s + "l = build_{}({});".format(which_build, size)
    ans = timeit.Timer(setup=setup, stmt="z=list(flatten(l))").timeit(n)
    return ans

print('length', 'none','some','lots')
for w in range(0, 500, 50):
    print(2*w+1, 
          get_time(w, 'none'), 
          get_time(w, 'some'),
          get_time(w, 'lots'))
```

produces

```
length none some lots
1 0.0012789969332516193 0.0006600483320653439 0.000653265044093132
101 0.030214487109333277 0.06863495009019971 0.10554128512740135
201 0.05980244372040033 0.188231083098799 0.3237948380410671
301 0.08960435865446925 0.3752179825678468 0.6493003228679299
401 0.11986956000328064 0.6066137161105871 1.147628225851804
501 0.14737469609826803 0.9323012446984649 1.7087256000377238
601 0.18555369088426232 1.2575508910231292 2.2957410947419703
701 0.20820995513349771 1.712264522910118 3.094764341134578
801 0.23618148919194937 2.100640726275742 4.079551971051842
901 0.26863432209938765 2.617169467266649 4.858607416041195
```

[image: simple plot of time vs nesting]

Comment: Indeed, the real factor here is the level of nesting. If M is the nesting level, the algorithm cost varies with M as well as N.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I wonder if an iterative flattener would perform a lot better here.  You'd exchange function call overhead for local stack ops, but given the function penalty that might be a net win. [Same number of things to do, but the cost might be cheaper.]

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. There is no way around having to loop through every nested list, but maintaining your own stack *could* be a viable workaround.

Comment: It doesn't really explain why it's quadratic though. Since the depth and number of elements in `l` are both O(N) and we touch each element once and each Iterator once.